# how to programatically upgrade (or be notified) of new versions of external tools?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dependencies, version, dependency-management

I am running a large number of federated tools on AWS EC2s, what is the best practice for automatically getting latest version of these tools installed on the 'dev env' EC2s rather than specifying a particular version per tool to install in the AWS startup scripts?

Not talking about java libraries here...some example tools I would like latest versions of auto-maintained for:

- Apache Spark
- Apache Hive
- Presto (by Facebook)
- Kafka
- ..etc

Comment: Are you building your own EC2 instances for HADOOP or are you using  EMR?

Comment: EMR not hadoop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write shell scripts for your each tool which contains steps to install new version , uninstall old version . and run it through ansible on all your ec2-instances. 
[Link](https://deliciousbrains.com/automating-server-setup-ansible/)

Comment: that still involves hardcoding the versions of each tool? i couldn't see where it specifies 'latest' of mysql?